# In visual studio code how to download a zip file when user install the extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Right now my extension needs a package to work. Due to some reasons, I cannot ship this in the vsix. So when a user installs the extension and clicks on any function the call comes to the activate function for the first time then I download the package(zip) file. But I want to download the zip file when a user clicks on the install extension itself.

Is it possible to download a zip file when the user clicks on the install button in the visual studio code?

please let me know if you need any further info.

Thanks,
Akhil

Comment: If the `activationEvents` has `*` maybe you can store a flag in the [storage](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage) wether you downloaded the zip or not.

Comment: "But I want to download the zip file when a user clicks on the install extension itself" is impossible. None of your code is executed at that moment, so no download can be triggered.

Comment: @LexLi none of the code is triggered but can we specify something in the package.json or something like that? If I install Go extension after install without any user action it downloads some tools. So in the same way can we download zip?

Comment: @MoshFeu my question is how to download the file after extension install without the user clicking any command. Like now user clicks on install extension and after extension installation, he will click any command then it checks whether the file is present or not if it is not present download the file. So now I want to download this file automatically after user clicks on install extension. Like some post install script?

Comment: The Go extension is open source, https://github.com/golang/vscode-go so if you wonder how it downloads the extra bits, review its source code.